# Set window manager's meta key depending on connected Xserver

Tags: x11, keyboard, remote

## Situation

A linux server is running an xdm supporting XDMCP, it is connected to from various different Linux and OS X boxes using XDMCP via an `X -query <server>` command.

Once the user is logged in the window manager is started, which is mostly controlled from the keyboard using an assigned meta key.

## Problem

The assigned meta key needs to depend on the platform of the box that connects to the linux server. How do I figure out what the platform is behind the connected X server?

## Thoughts

I cannot use the DISPLAY environment variable to switch on, the IPs of the connecting boxes are assigned by DHCP and give no clue what the platform of the box is.

I know the -class option to X can be used to set the display class, which then could be used to set defaults for the various display classes in Xresources. However I don't know how to get the class of the connected Xserver from the command line (or a little custom C program) and furthermore, I don't know how to get the value of an Xresource that would be configured with that class.

Ideally the used meta key could be configured on the box running the X server, so that the linux server running the xdm does not need any reconfiguration when a new type of platform is introduced in the setup.

What is the best way to go about this? Is it possible to determine the platform the X server is running on? Can some configuration option be passed from the Xserver to the window manager scripts? Is there a better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem would be easy to solve if you set up keyboard mappings so that the same keysym and modifier is assigned to the Meta key everywhere.

---

You can get some information about the server via the [xrdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xrdb) program. The server defines some property which [`xrdb`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xrdb.1.html) makes available through preprocessing. You can print them out with `xrdb -symbols`. For example,

```
xrdb -Dsymbols | sed -n 's/-DSERVERHOST=//p'
```

prints the hostname of the X server. You can define specific resources for a particular server host with C preprocessing constructs:

```
#ifdef SRVR_darkstar
…
#endif
```

Here's a shell script that turns xrdb symbols into shell environment variables. Use it with something like `eval "$(xrdb_sh_prefix=X_ xrdb-sh)"`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Access xrdb #define's from the shell

# For each binding that xrdb(1) would give to the preprocessor, print
# NAME=VALUE for -DNAME=VALUE.
# If $xrdb_sh_export is not empty, also print "export NAME".
# If $xrdb_sh_prefix is not empty, prefix it to each NAME in output.
# Shell metacharacters are preceded by `\' in VALUEs. NAMEs are
# assumed to be admissible C identifiers.
# Example:
#   xrdb_sh_export=y xrdb_sh_prefix=X_ xrdb-sh
# outputs somthing like
#    X_SERVERHOST=drongo
#    export X_SERVERHOST
#    X_VENDOR=The\ XFree86\ Project\,\ Inc
#    export X_VENDOR
# ...
# The output of this program is typically used in a Bourne shell thus:
#   eval "`xrdb_sh_prefix=X_ xrdb-sh`"

if [ -n "$xrdb_sh_export" ]; then
  awk_export='print "export " name'
fi
awk -v prefix="$xrdb_sh_prefix" '
  /^-D/ {
    $0 = substr($0, 3)
    eq = match($0, /=/)
    name = (prefix) (eq ? substr($0, 1, eq-1) : $0)
    if (eq) {
        $0 = substr($0, eq+1)
        sub(/^\"/, ""); sub(/\"$/, "")
        gsub(/[^0-9A-Z_a-z]/, "\\\\&")
    } else {
        $0 = ""
    }
    print name "=" $0
    '"$awk_export"'
  }
  /^exit=[0-9]+$/ {sub(/^.*=/, ""); exit $0}
' <<EOF
`{ xrdb "$@" -symbols || echo exit=$?; } | $sort || echo exit=$?`
EOF
```

---

Another approach would be to set custom properties on the root window from the server side, for example with [`xprop`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xprop.1.html). Query those properties (again with `xprop`) from the client side.

```
xprop -set Server_arch "$(uname -m)"
```

Comment: Unfortunately option one is a no-go since I cannot require users to set up their keymap in a certain way just for this one server, they will be connecting to other servers and using their X locally which could get messed up or require people to do all kinds of reconfiguration on their own boxes or on the other servers.

Comment: @wich You'd be setting up the keymap by a call to `xmodmap` or `xkb`, or a setting in `/etc/xorg.conf`, on the X server side.

Comment: The X_SERVERHOST also seems a no-go, for me it just gives the IP of the box running the X server, just like it is in $DISPLAY in the environment. As mentioned it's a DHCP environment, so I cannot infer anything from the IP itself.

Comment: re: keymap Exactly, which is what I cannot require from people, adding some info tag in whichever way is one thing, but asking people to modify their keymap is not okay in this environment

Comment: As for `xprop`, I could not get it working yet, but aside from that the problem is that the X server is not yet running before the `X -query` is made, and after that xprop does not have access on the connecting box, an xhost +<IP from $DISPLAY> would need to be executed on the server box, or something similar. Even then my xprop failed for some unknown reason, which I have not yet been able to solve.

Comment: When playing with `xprop` I did find `xdpyinfo` which gave me something useful, it showed that the connecting OS X boxes have some Apple specific extensions `Apple-WM` and `Apple-DRI`, I could switch on the existence of that, but it would be quite a kludge and there is of course no guarantee that a similar kludge would exist for other platforms...

Comment: Is there any way I can add some info to the output of `xrdb -symbols` or `xdpyinfo` by some configuration or command line argument of the X server?

Comment: @wich The output of `xdpyinfo` and `xrdb -symbols` are fixed by the server and by xrdb respectively. I do think the right way would be to set a good keymap on the server, before the user logs in. If the user wants to use a different meta key, their keymap will override the prior setting as desired.